# Uninstallation method not triggered in child theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, uninstallation

I'm currently working on a WordPress child theme and I needed a way to delete all the data on uninstall, so I found [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/#method-1-register_uninstall_hook) in the WordPress documentation.

I tested `uninstall.php` or the `register_uninstall_hook` but it doesn't work when the theme is uninstalled.

Here's my uninstall code:

```
function uninstallMe() {
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
        die('Heey dude, wanna coffee?');
    }
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}coffee_tags";
    $wpdb->query($sql);

    exec("crontab -l | grep -v 'mycustomcron0047.php' | crontab -");

    $sysPath = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ;
    unlink($sysPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
    unlink($sysPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mycustomcron0047.php');
}
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'uninstallMe' );
```

Is there an alternative way to remove data on child theme uninstall? Or a way to make default ways work?